# Group by Unique Count

Tags: r, data.table

Has anyone been able to successfully get the  `library(data.table)` in R to calculate a unique count correctly with the "by" function.

Please see my syntax.

```
x <- case_dt[,.(N=uniqueN(case_dt$case.id)), by=territory]
```

this code yields the following output. Which is not grouped by territory. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just remove the `case_dt` and `$` operator:

```
case_dt[,.(N=uniqueN(case.id)),by=territory]
```

Consider this reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[,.(N = uniqueN(cyl)), by = gear]
   gear N
1:    4 2
2:    3 3
3:    5 3
```

This works because `cyc` is being subset `by = gear`.

In contrast:

```
mtcars[,.(N = uniqueN(mtcars$cyl)), by = gear]
   gear N
1:    4 3
2:    3 3
3:    5 3
```

This is because you are calling `uniqueN` on `mtcars$cyl` from the global environment for each group.

So really, it's like calling this every group:

```
uniqueN(mtcars$cyl)
[1] 3
```